# how to pass parameter from login page to navigation drawer xamarin form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

App.cs

```
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();



            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new login());


        }
```

login.cs

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage(test.Text));

        }
```

mainpage.cs

public MainPage(string id)
    {

```
    InitializeComponent();

    menuList = new List<MasterPageItem>();


    var page1 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Item 1", Icon = "itemIcon1.png", TargetType = typeof(TestPage1) };
    var page2 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Item 2", Icon = "itemIcon2.png", TargetType = typeof(TestPage2) };
    // Adding menu items to menuList
    menuList.Add(page1);
    menuList.Add(page2);



    navigationDrawerList.ItemsSource = menuList;

    // Initial navigation, this can be used for our home page
    Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TestPage1)));
}


private void OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{

    var item = (MasterPageItem)e.SelectedItem;
    Type page = item.TargetType;

    Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));
    IsPresented = false;
}
```

i have login page when i click on login button it generate id, i want to send this id to main page, which i have already done it. Now from main page i want to send this id to pages, for example if i click on page 1, main page send this id to page1, so basically i need to send id from main page to all page anyone help with that what to do in mainpage.cs when i click on page it send id to that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this in `OnMenuItemSelected`:

`Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType, Tempid));`

mainpage.cs

```
string Tempid;
public MainPage(string id) {

InitializeComponent();
Tempid=id;
menuList = new List<MasterPageItem>();


var page1 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Item 1", Icon = "itemIcon1.png", TargetType = typeof(TestPage1) };
var page2 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Item 2", Icon = "itemIcon2.png", TargetType = typeof(TestPage2) };
// Adding menu items to menuList
menuList.Add(page1);
menuList.Add(page2);



navigationDrawerList.ItemsSource = menuList;

// Initial navigation, this can be used for our home page
Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TestPage1)));
}


private void OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{

var item = (MasterPageItem)e.SelectedItem;
Type page = item.TargetType;

 Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType, Tempid));
IsPresented = false;
}
```

Hope this may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that...
If all your pages need to access this 'Id' parameter, I would make a navigation helper (static one or registered in your service container). Here is the interface of the service I could make:

```
public interface NavigationHelper
{
    ///
    /// To call from your application login page
    ///
    public void RegisterNavigationId(string currentSessionNavId);

    ///
    /// To access the 'Id' (without changing it) from everywhere you want
    ///
    public NavigationId{ get; }
}
```

So each page of your application could access this helper easily, as we said:

- with the static helper instance, ie: NavigationHelper.Instance.Id
- or by injecting your helper class into your views or viewmodels (depending from where you want to navigate).

This parameter could also be part of a "settings" class if it never change along the session...

Or last idea for you, you can make inherit all your pages from one abstract page that need an 'Id' in its constructor...

As you want !

Comment: but if i have id in textbox of login page i want to pass this id to all page how i gonna do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a property / value that should be publicly available within the application scope (on any screen), it will make sense to "persist" it in one place. It can be a public property within `Application` class. [Properties Dicitonary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#properties-dictionary), property of `MasterDetailPage`, SQL and etc. depends on your needs.

Passing the same property `from main page to all page` simply does not make sense.